# Menu não aparece na versão mobile

Tags: php, menu, require

Bom dia a todos, to finalizando uma página que possui um menu externo, solicitado no PHP com o require, também já tentei o include, mas ainda continua com o mesmo problema, conforme imagens abaixo o menu só aparece na versão desktop, na versão chrome mobile não aparece, alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Como eu disse acima, é uma pagina normal em PHP, tanto a pagina do print, quanto ao menu.php, e nenhuma das páginas que é necessário o menu, na versão mobile não aparece;

[image: versão desktop]

[image: versão android chrome]

Código

```
<?php
require 'head.php';
require 'conn/conexao.php';

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

?>
<style type="text/css">
#kit{
    position:absolute;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-40%;
    margin-top:-250px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 8px 22px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
#escrita{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#333;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:link {
   text-decoration:none;
}
a:visited { 
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
 } 
a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
table.tabela{
    text-align:center;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:70%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    margin-top:2%;
}
table.tabela tr td {
    border:1px outset;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>

<div id="kit" align="center"> 


<?php 

  $hora = date('H:i');
  if($hora >= '13:30' && $hora <= '22:00' ){
      $turno = 'Turno B';
  }elseif($hora >= '22:01' && $hora <= '04:59' ){
      $turno = 'Turno C';
  }else{
      $turno = 'Turno A';
  }
   ?>

<form action="" method="post">   


<table class="tabela">


<tr>
    <td colspan="8">
        <p id="escrita">Reporte de produção por turno: 
<select name="turno" style="width:100px; height:40px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:17px; color:#F00;">
          <option value="<?php echo $turno; ?>"><?php echo $turno; ?></option>
          <option value="Turno A">Turno A</option>
          <option value="Turno B">Turno B</option>
          <option value="Turno C">Turno C</option>
</select>
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')); ?>" name="data_reporte" style="width:130px; height:35px;" />
</p>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>Número</td>
    <td>Máquina</td>
    <td>Grupo</td>
    <td>Agulhagem</td>
    <td>Produção</td>
    <td>Setup</td>
    <td>Pares Segunda qual.</td>
    <td>Peso Terceira qual.</td>
  </tr>


<script type="text/javascript" src="meia/js/jquery.min2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="meia/js/jquery.wallform.js"></script>



<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM maquinas ORDER BY id ASC";
    $disp_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while($data = $disp_sql->fetch_array())
    { 
        $num       = $data['num'];
        $maq       = $data['maq'];
        $grupo     = $data['grupo'];
        $agulha    = $data['agulha'];

?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $num; ?><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num; ?>" name="num[]" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $maq; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $grupo; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $agulha; ?></td>
    <td>
    <input type="number" name="producao[]" min="0" max="500" style="width:50px;" tabindex="<?php echo $num; ?>" id="<?php echo $num; ?>" onkeyup="Enter('<?php echo ($num + 1); ?>');" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="setup[]" value="s" /></td>
    <td>
    <input type="number" name="segunda[]" value="0" min="0" max="5000" style="width:50px;" id="<?php echo "1-".$num; ?>" onkeyup="Enter('<?php echo ("1-".($num + 1)); ?>');" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="number" name="terceira[]" value="0" min="0" max="5000" style="width:50px;" id="<?php echo "2-".$num; ?>" onkeyup="Enter('<?php echo ("2-".($num + 1)); ?>');" />
    </td>
  </tr>


<?php } ?>  

  <tr>
    <td colspan="8"><input type="submit" value="Reportar produção" style="width:150px; margin:5px;" /></td>
  </tr>
  <input type="hidden" name="teste" value="teste" />
</form>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Enter(idinput){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      document.getElementById(idinput).focus();
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="meia/js/jquery.min2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="meia/js/jquery.wallform.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poste parte do código, para podermos tentar ajudar com o que está acontecendo. Sem o código não somos adivinhas :)

Comment: Denis poste a parte do código HTML/CSS envolvidas no problema. Só com o relato e as imagens não da para te responder...

Comment: @DavidAlves obrigado por responder, acrescentei o código.

Comment: @hugocsl obrigado por responder, acrescentei o código.

Comment: @DenisL.Murara imagino que o código do cabeçalho esteja dentro do arquivo `head.php` este é o código mais importante

Comment: Cara acho que esse Menu era um include ou algo assim, pois ele não venho no código que vc postou. Só veio a tabela....

Comment: Se possível poste o código depois de renderizado na página e não o arquivo .PHP. Vai no Browser, aperta Ctrl+U e pega o que estiver lá com o menu montado. Depois posta o CSS dele completo tb com os @media etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Media Queries no seu CSS, para tira o margin-top da sua div, que esta ficando por cima do menu, na versão mobile.

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
#kit{
    top:0%;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
 }
}
```

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado Adriano! funcionou perfeito.

Comment: Por nada, Precisando de ajudar e só falar.